# sort and give value to a two dimensional object in a class based on value of another object c++

Tags: c++, class, sorting

I am going to sort a two dimensional vector object in a class based on values of another object in the class. My class looks like this:
           class problem
    {
    public:
       vector>  bit;
       vector>      WaitingTime; 
       vector                processingJob;
    } problem1;
    const int i=3;
    const int j=4;
I want to sort the 2D values of `problem1.bit[i][j]`(size of first dimension is 3 and size of second dimensio is 4) based on values of `problem1.processingJob[j]` but I do not know how to apply sort function to this. I could find some topics for 1D variable but not any topic for 2D object. 
Therefore for lowest value of processingJob, lets say we have the following:

```
  processingJob[0]=73  
  processingJob[1]=44  
 processingJob[2]=32  
   processingJob[3]=52
```

Here processingJob[2] has the lowest value and therefore:
`bit[0][2]=bit[1][2]=bit[2][2]=1`
The 2nd lowest value is processingJob[1]=44 and therefore:

```
 bit[0][1] and bit[1][1] and bit[2][1]=2
```

The 3rd lowest value is processingJob[4]=52 and therefore in the output I have:

```
bit[0][3] and bit[1][3] and bit[2][3]=3
```

The largest value is processingJob[0]=73 and therefore in the output I have:

```
bit[0][0] and bit[1][0] and bit[2][0]=4
```

In fact it needs just sorting based processingJob and then giving the order number to each bit[i][j]

Comment: You could consider making bit one dimensional and make it's size i*j

Comment: @super It should be two dimensional because of other parts of the code.

Comment: It is basically the same thing. Instead of writing bit[x][y] you can write bit[x+y*size_of_x_column]. Anyhow, it was just a suggestion to make the sorting easier.

Comment: So something like sort( bit,bit[x+y*size_of_x_column], processingJob);
Because size of processingjob is j and i have bit[i][j] and first dimension is i.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, can you please clarify what do you need sorted?

Comment: @L.Y.Sim Revised and added more details.

Comment: I should be able to help you with that, I'll try to give you an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your class (which formatting is messed up in the question):

```
class problem {
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<short int>>  bit;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>>      WaitingTime;
    std::vector<int>                     processingJob;
};
```

I was able to solve the problem using this code:

```
// initializing a 3 x 4 problem 
// I'm just writing this down so you know what data I used to test my code
   problem problem1{};
   problem1.processingJob = { 73, 44, 32, 52 };
   problem1.bit = std::vector<std::vector<short int>>(3, std::vector<short int>(4, 0));

// one way to solve this would be to use std::pairs to pair elements in processingJob 
// to their respective indices
   std::vector<std::pair<int, size_t>> v_pairs;         // store the pairs in this vector
   for (size_t i = 0; i != problem1.processingJob.size(); ++i) {
       v_pairs.push_back({ problem1.processingJob[i], i });
   }

// now sort the vector of pairs using std::sort. We sort with respect to the .first members 
// of the pair, which (if you recall) were the values copied from processingJob. 
// std::sort sorts by .first members by default.
   std::sort(v_pairs.begin(), v_pairs.end());

// now we can index the 2D 'bit' vector using indices paired to the processingJob elements
// we iterate through v_pairs to get said indices
   for (size_t k = 0; k != v_pairs.size(); ++k) {
       for (auto& subvector : problem1.bit) {
           // set the corresponding values
           subvector[v_pairs[k].second] = k + 1;
       }
   }
```

I can't claim that the code is typesafe as there is narrowing conversion at

```
subvector[v_pairs[k].second] = k + 1;
```

when the `size_t` typed `k` is converted to `short int`. But I'll leave the type safety and all that to you.

Also I can't claim the code to be most efficient, but it's at least a working starting point. I definitely agree with @[super](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7703024/super), I think using a 1D `vector` for `bit` instead of 2D would be better. It would be trivial to convert it from 2D to 1D so I'll also leave that to you.

You may also call `.reserve()` on `v_pairs` before you start adding elements to it if you have many elements to insert.